# QTableView disable sorting for some columns

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtcore, qt-signals

I am using QtableView(qt5.9) with 10 columns and want to disable sorting for 2nd and 3rd (only some) columns when the user clicks on the header of these columns.

- I use setsortingenabled flag to make my QtableView allow sorting
- Is there any signal which I should listen to on clicking of header and then call some appropraite method or deny sorting.

Comment: did you try to use [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details)  ?

Comment: @simon yes i tried QSortFilterProxyModel but i see only lessthan method useful there , also clicking on header calls sortbycolum of view so how in QSortFilterProxyModel i can prevent sorting any suggestions

Comment: maybe to can try the header signal [sortIndicatorChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#sortIndicatorChanged)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the header signal [sortIndicatorChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#sortIndicatorChanged) to restore the current sort indicator.

Example:

```
    connect(m_poTableView->header(), &QHeaderView::sortIndicatorChanged,
            this, &MyClass::HandleIndicatorChanged);


    MyClass::HandleIndicatorChanged(int logicalIndex, Qt::SortOrder eSort)
    {
       if (logicalIndex != 0)
       {
             this->m_poTableView->horizontalHeader()->setSortIndicator(
                0, this->m_poTableView->model()->sortOrder());
       }
    }
```

Comment: @mapuna do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 2):

An easier way (for me, at least) is to subclass the filter proxy and override sorting for just the disabled columns. The below code is in Python, but it is a simple translation to C++.

```
def CustomSorter(QtCor.QSortFilterProxyModel):
  def sort(self, column: int, order: QtCore.Qt.SortOrder) -> None:
    if column == 2 or column == 3:
      # Do nothing instead of sorting
      return
    else:
      # Sort as usual
      super().sort(column, order)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use in the case I only want to allow sorting column 2 (sOrder is a private int member of MyClass):

```
connect(ui->tableView->horizontalHeader(), &QHeaderView::sortIndicatorChanged, this, &MyClass::onSortIndicatorChanged);

void MyClass::onSortIndicatorChanged(int column, Qt::SortOrder order)
{
    if (column == 2){
        // Record the sort order when it is column 2
        sOrder = order;
    }
    else{
        // Restore the column 2 sort order
        ui->tableView->sortByColumn(2, sOrder);
    }
}
```