# QTableView: disable sort for some header columns

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using PyQT4 and have a QTableView with 2 columns:

```
...
self.model = MyTableModel()

self.proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(0)

self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView()
self.tableView.setModel(self.proxy)

self.selectionModel = QtGui.QItemSelectionModel(self.model)
self.tableView.setSelectionModel(self.selectionModel)

self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.tableView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
...
```

I want just the first column (#0) sortable by clicking on its header. The header of the second column (#1) should just ignore any click. I only found out, that it`s just possible to enable or disable the whole header row for clicking/sorting.

Can someone please help how I can disable the event handlers for some specific header columns?

Comment: If you don't want to sort specific column you can override the `QSortFilterProxyModel` and reimplement the `lessThan` function.

Comment: This also could help [disable sorting for some columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195261/qtableview-disable-sorting-for-some-columns)

Comment: Thank you Simon, your idea with `QSortFilterProxyModel` and `lessThan` seems to work. But I think it is a little bit inefficient, because the `lessThan` function will be unnecessarily called for each row. It would be nice if there is a more performant solution.

Comment: It will be called anyway. If you find some better performance please share.